# QKeySequence differences between PySide and PySide2

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside2

As I'm currently porting a gui application from Python 2.7.14/PySide 1.2.4 to Python 3.7.1/PySide2 5.11.2 I'm encountering a few problems with the shortcut machinery. More specifically:

- `QKeySequence` instantiation seems to return different/surprising results in PySide2 compared to PySide.
- The `+` operators on `Qt.Key_*` enums don't seem to return the expected results. For example `QKeySequence(Qt.SHIFT + Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z)` doesn't seem to work properly.
- When using string codes for instantiation of `QKeySequences` it works, for example `QKeySequence("Shift+Ctrl+Z")` seems functional.
- Instantiation with `QKeySequence.StandardKey` like `QKeySequence(QKeySequence.Redo)` simply crashes in PySide2.

Are these known bugs? Did something change in the expected usage? Did I miss [something in the docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QKeySequence.html#qkeysequence)?

#### Win7x64/Python 3.7.1/PySide2 5.11.2 *(disfunctional/crashing)*

---

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Test QKeySequence equality/matching in PySide2."""
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QKeySequence

sequence_a = QKeySequence("Shift+Ctrl+Z")
sequence_b = QKeySequence(Qt.SHIFT + Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z)

# string representation
print(sequence_a.toString())
print(sequence_b.toString())

print("-"*20)

# equality/matching
print(sequence_a.matches(sequence_b))
print(sequence_a == sequence_b)

print("-"*20)

# this causes a crash in PySide2 (Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005))
print(QKeySequence(QKeySequence.Redo))

# Ctrl+Shift+Z
# [
# --------------------
# PySide2.QtGui.QKeySequence.SequenceMatch.NoMatch
# False
# --------------------
# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

#### Win7x64/Python 2.7.14/PySide 1.2.4 *(working)*

---

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Test QKeySequence equality/matching in PySide."""
from PySide.QtCore import Qt
from PySide.QtGui import QKeySequence

sequence_a = QKeySequence("Shift+Ctrl+Z")
sequence_b = QKeySequence(Qt.SHIFT + Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z)

# string representation
print(sequence_a.toString())
print(sequence_b.toString())

print("-"*20)

# equality/matching
print(sequence_a.matches(sequence_b))
print(sequence_a == sequence_b)

print("-"*20)

# this works in PySide
print(QKeySequence(QKeySequence.Redo))

# Ctrl+Shift+Z
# Ctrl+Shift+Z
# --------------------
# PySide.QtGui.QKeySequence.SequenceMatch.ExactMatch
# True
# --------------------
# PySide.QtGui.QKeySequence(67108953, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: in PySide 1.2.4 on Linux I get the same behavior in both versions. What do you get when you run: `import PySide print(PySide.__version__)`?

Comment: _Python3:_ `$ python -c "import PySide2; print(PySide2.__version__)"
5.11.2` _Python2:_ `$ python -c "import PySide; print PySide.__version__"
1.2.4`. Btw. running on Windows7x64.

Comment: PySide + Python2: `Ctrl+Shift+Z
Ctrl+Shift+Z
--------------------
PySide.QtGui.QKeySequence.SequenceMatch.ExactMatch
True
--------------------
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
`

Comment: PySide + Python3: `Ctrl+Shift+Z
[
--------------------
PySide.QtGui.QKeySequence.SequenceMatch.NoMatch
False
--------------------
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
`

Comment: PySide2 + python2: `Ctrl+Shift+Z
Ctrl+Shift+Z
--------------------
PySide2.QtGui.QKeySequence.SequenceMatch.ExactMatch
True
--------------------
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: PySide2 + python3:  `Ctrl+Shift+Z
[
--------------------
PySide2.QtGui.QKeySequence.SequenceMatch.NoMatch
False
--------------------
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: In conclusion in Linux `QKeySequence(QKeySequence.Redo)` always crashes, in python2 it works matches but not in python3. That is, good or bad behavior is maintained in pyside and pyside2

Comment: Have you tried with python2 and PySide2?

Comment: Thanks for testing along. Is there something different with the enum. types in Python3? Something with their internal `int` representation? Something with their `__add__` ? Why would there be a difference in Python3 at this point?

Comment: I think so, I'm finding out. If I execute the following: `print(Qt.SHIFT + Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z)` I get in python2: `100663386` and in python3: `91`. On the other hand, if I execute: `print(Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z)` get the same result in both

Comment: I haven't tried with Python2 and PySide2 as I'm developing on Windows atm and there seems to be [no official wheel available on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/5.11.2/#files) for Python27 on that platform. I could spawn up a virtual machine though, haven't thought of that direction though.

Comment: Yes, 2 summands seem to work correctly across both interpreter and framework versions: `print(Qt.SHIFT + Qt.Key_Z)`  # 33554522 `print(QKeySequence(Qt.SHIFT + Qt.Key_Z).toString())`  # "Shift+Z"

Comment: I am analyzing the algorithm, maybe some bad conversion of data type between C ++ and python.

Comment: Maybe something with operator precedence changed in Py3 compared to Py2. This `print(Qt.SHIFT + (Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z))`/`print(QKeySequence(Qt.SHIFT + (Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z)).toString())` delivers the same result in both interpreter versions. However, when adding up integers, order shouldn't matter, i'd think!?

Comment: So it seems, but it seems you've found a workaround: group 2 to 2. :-)

Comment: In PyQt5 that behavior does not exist so I think that shiboken has not correctly implemented the sum and instead of returning an enum returns another integer that is outside the enum.

Comment: Grouping 2 doesn't always work either: `print((Qt.SHIFT + Qt.CTRL) + Qt.Key_Z)`  # *Py2:* `100663386` *Py3:* `91`

Comment: Use `Qt.SHIFT + (Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z)` with that it works

Comment: Ok, sure using `Qt.SHIFT + (Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z)` solves the problem now. Wondering if there is some rule in that or if it's just trial/error now when 3 summands are involved as enums!? Are 2 always safe? This would possibly classify as a binding bug!? Should it be reported?

Comment: Yes, report it, I was going to tell you that since PySide2 has many bugs.

Comment: Another option: `Qt.ShiftModifier | Qt.ControlModifier | Qt.Key_Z)`

Comment: Another option: `Qt.ShiftModifier | Qt.CTRL | Qt.Key_Z`

Comment: I also recommend posting the workaround as answer.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Posted the current workarounds as answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As for now, two possible workarounds have emerged:

---

- **Error:** `QKeySequence(Qt.SHIFT + Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z).toString()`  --> `"["`
- **Fix with enforced precedence:** `QKeySequence(Qt.SHIFT + (Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_Z)).toString()`  --> `"Ctrl+Shift+Z"`
- **Fix with bitwise or operator:** `QKeySequence(Qt.ShiftModifier | Qt.CTRL | Qt.Key_Z).toString()`  --> `"Ctrl+Shift+Z"`

While they seem to solve the direct problem at hand, I don't find them to be all that great for various reasons. The general issue may still possibly qualify as PySide2 bug!?

Comment: Enums should generelly only be combined using `|` - using a `+` was a usage error from your side. However, the crash when using `QKeySequence.Redo` definitely qualifies as a bug and imho should be reported

Comment: @Felix Usage of the `+` operator like this is given as example in the [docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QKeySequence.html#detailed-description) a [few times](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QKeySequence.html#gnu-emacs-style-key-sequences). So I wouldn't really count that as a classical usage error. In fact it even kind of seems like the preferred usage.